# Sort a structured Numpy array based on a single column while preserving order in other columns

Tags: numpy, sorting, structured-array

I want to sort the following input by 1st column:

```
a = np.array([(2, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3)], dtype=[('c1', int), ('c2', int)])

[[2, 1],
[1, 2],
[2, 3]]
```

I've tried `a.sort(order='c1')` followed by `print(a[::-1]`.

Expected output (2nd column order is preserved):

```
[[2, 1],
[2, 3],
[1, 2]]
```

Actual output:

```
[[2, 3],
[2, 1],
[1, 2]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it. Those dtype tuples are bound together at a deeper level than rows. They are fields, not columns. You could sort `x=a['c1']` and write it back.

```
In [547]: a = np.array([(2, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3)], dtype=[('c1', int), ('c2', int)])
     ...: 
In [548]: a
Out[548]: array([(2, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3)], dtype=[('c1', '<i8'), ('c2', '<i8')])
In [549]: x=np.sort(a['c1'])
In [550]: x
Out[550]: array([1, 2, 2])
In [551]: a['c1']=x
In [552]: a
Out[552]: array([(1, 1), (2, 2), (2, 3)], dtype=[('c1', '<i8'), ('c2', '<i8')])
```

Comment: Doesn't this just do the same thing I did, but use more memory? The output is identical.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure I've figured it out. Negate it:

```
a['c1'] = -a['c1']
a.sort(order='c1')
a['c1'] = -a['c1']
print(a)
```

which results in

```
[(2, 1) (2, 3) (1, 2)]
```

I won't accept this answer yet in case someone has a more optimal solution.